# How to put the variable in a certain order after using "Solve[]"

Tags: equation-solving, core-language

I have this code:

```
eq1 = 4 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x11 == 5;
eq2 = 5 x1 - 3 x2 + 3 x11 == 99;
eq3 = 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 4 x11 == 7;
system = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
solution = Solve[system]
```

and the output is:

```
{{x1 -> 2574/161, x11 -> 1094/161, x2 -> 71/161}}
```

I would like the output to go in order i.e. `x1`, `x2`, and then `x11`, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Use `x[1],x[2],x[1,1]` (or `x[1],x[2],x[11]`) instead of `x1,x2,x11`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: BTW, you can even suppress the output of `x11` by using `Solve[system, {x1, x2}, {x11}]`, if you want to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Solve` will return the solutions in the order requested:

```
solution = Solve[system, {x1, x2, x11}]
(*  {{x1 -> 2574/161, x2 -> 71/161, x11 -> 1094/161}}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
SortBy[#, {StringLength @ SymbolName[#[[1]]] &}] & /@ solution
```

> {{x1 -> 2574/161, x2 -> 71/161, x11 -> 1094/161}}

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
solution /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, c, b}

(*  {{x1 -> 2574/161, x2 -> 71/161, x11 -> 1094/161}}   *)
```

Have fun!